# Difference between power and rate of change of energy according to first law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

When we say, according to first law of thermodynamics, that $dU=dQ+dW$, and the rate of this is $$\frac{dU}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\mathrm{Energy}$$ is this the same thing as power? I think power is the energy debited per second, while, in the first law, we are calculating the amount energy that enters the system and leaves the system per time. Are they considered the same thing?

Comment: The first law does not talk about power. $\Delta U$ represents the change in internal energy between two states. It does not speak of the time it takes to achieve that.

Comment: we can talk about the heat rate

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, neither $dQ$ nor $dW$ are exactly infinitesimal state variables: Notation is misleading. For example, you cannot directly integrate $dQ$ and obtain Q, as Q is a path-dependent quantity. Actually, this is one of the reasons why you need to write $$\begin{aligned}dQ=TdS\\dW=PdV\end{aligned}$$ to be able to use simple calculus and integrate them.

That said, how you define your power is also ambiguous: $U$ is the *internal energy*, so if you are interested at the change of internal energy and denote that as some kind of power, sure, you can say $P\equiv\frac{dU}{dt}$. Nonetheless, one is most of the time interested in the power as the change of mechanic energy, kinetic energy + potential energy, so this definition is not that convenient.

You can think of car engines as an example: Even though it is a thermodynamic process with heat going out and internal energy being used, power of the engine is defined only with respect to the mechanical output that it can produce.